# CardView and RecyclerView divider behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use `RecyclerView` with `CardView` as an single item of the list.
I want to implement horizontal list, with `LayoutManager` it is really easy.
So I started to implement it. It seems that everything works, but not as I expected here is the result using CardView as an list item.

[image]

Looks pretty good, but I haven't set any paddings, dividers and rounded corners.
Here is my XML for card view item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
       >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:src="@drawable/androidsss"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Also there is something like small divider at the bottom of layout.
I haven't specified any.
Here is my setting up code for RecyclerView

```
 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
 //   mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
    mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Interesting thing that with simple item, not card view, everything works as expected. Here is an example.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
        android:text="Hello World !!"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where is the problem, is it my fault or bug ?

Comment: Maybe it's feature of a CardView? I mean that's why we use cardViews - to get shadows and so on.

Comment: If you don't want padding, rounded corners and drop shadows, then simply don't use CardView. A normal FrameLayout etc would do just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spaces you can see are **compat paddings** and they're visible only on pre-Lollipop devices (or everywhere if you set `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`). You can find values [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) (CardView's doc).

> Before L, CardView adds padding to its content and draws shadows to that area. This padding amount is equal to maxCardElevation + (1 - cos45) * cornerRadius on the sides and maxCardElevation * 1.5 + (1 - cos45) * cornerRadius on top and bottom.

Also, as far as I can see, there is some default radius for `CardView`'s corner (probably it is 2dp).

You can try any tricks to avoid these spaces or (IMHO it's better) consider if you should make  *view with custom background*, like simple "tile". 
[Here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage) you have some info from Google about design.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior of `CardView`, however you can modify how it should look, like removing the border radius and etc by adding attributes to your `CardView` declaration.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor='#ffffff'>
```

For more information must visit this to clip shadows
https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:src="@drawable/androidsss"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">