# RuntimeException in one case. NullExeption - getBackStackCount()

Tags: android, runtimeexception, fragment-backstack

Only when my app was off (freed resourses for other apps) and when i again opened it, i got this exaption. If i myself closed app, all it worked.

```
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.john.testOne/com.john.testOne.StartPageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.john.testOne.StartPageActivity.resetToolbarNavigation(StartPageActivity.java:177)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.john.testOne.BaseFragment.onAttach(BaseFragment.java:25)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1030)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1241)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2048)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:154)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:289)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.john.testOne.StartPageActivity.onCreate(StartPageActivity.java:34)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 
11-10 22:00:10.007 6255-6255/com.john.testOne E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's my Activity:

```
public class StartPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseFragment.BaseFragmentActions {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_page_activity);;
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment mFragment = new MainFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container,mFragment)
                    .commit();
        initNavigation();
    }
}
```

MainFragment extends BaseFragment....

and BaseFragment:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private static String TAG = "BaseFragment";
    private BaseFragmentActions baseFragmentActions;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "onAttach = ");
        try {
            baseFragmentActions = (BaseFragmentActions)(StartPageActivity)getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(((StartPageActivity)getActivity()).toString() + " must implement interface BaseFragmentActions");
        }
        baseFragmentActions.resetToolbarNavigation(getBackStackCount()!=0);
    }

    @Override
    @CallSuper
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        baseFragmentActions.resetToolbarNavigation((getBackStackCount() -1 )!= 0);

    }

    private int getBackStackCount() {
        int b = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        return b;
    }

    public interface BaseFragmentActions {
        public void resetToolbarNavigation(boolean backNavigationEnabled);
    }
}
```

If will need

```
baseFragmentActions.resetToolbarNavigation(getBackStackCount()!=0);    

             ^^
             ||
             ||

at com.john.testOne.BaseFragment.onAttach(BaseFragment.java:25)
```

I add resetToolbarNavigation........

```
        @Override
    public void resetToolbarNavigation(boolean backNavigationEnabled) {
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(backNavigationEnabled);//------------------177
//        mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_add);
        if (backNavigationEnabled) {
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   // Log.i("resetToolbarNavigation", "setNavigationOnClickListener");
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            initNavigation();
            syncState();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused, why don't you post the code where the exception actually happens?

Comment: Which line number 177 in class `StartPageActivity`?

Comment: Browse the end of the main question/ i added //177

Comment: I was wrong. In the studio I changed information, i add corectly //177

Comment: It means, your `mActionBar==null`

Comment: yap bool backNavigationEnabled got from BaseFragment baseFragmentActions.resetToolbarNavigation(getBackStackCount()!=0);

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: then this method translated null.

Comment: I have modified answer again, and now?

Comment: this exeption only when app was off (freed resourses for other apps) and when i again opened it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
@Override
public void resetToolbarNavigation(boolean backNavigationEnabled) {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(backNavigationEnabled);
    if (backNavigationEnabled) {
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Log.i("resetToolbarNavigation", "setNavigationOnClickListener");
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        initNavigation();
        syncState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: Maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated

Comment: Show your method `resetToolbarNavigation` in `StartPageActivity`

Comment: i added to main question

Comment: this exaption after a rotation too